# Hibernate buildSessionFactory fails in Maven build

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I have a project which is using Hibernate 4 (deployed and in production). I decided to convert it to a Maven project. The project builds fine in eclipse with no errors shown. When I attempt to build the project in Maven I get an error. I can't figure out what the difference is and why it builds and deploys fine from within Eclipe but fails in the Maven build. I would think that I would get a compile error in Eclipse if this were truly an error. Here is the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project speed: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \Users\SteveS\workspace\speed2\src\com\newpig\speed2\data\datahandlers\SyteLineHibernateUtils.java:[25,23] error: method buildSessionFactory in class Configuration cannot be applied to given types;
```

The buildSessionFactory call in SyteLineHibernateUtils:

```
static {
    try {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("/com/newpig/speed2/syteLine.cfg.xml");

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.newpig");
        logger.error("Error in SyteLineHibernateUtils. Static configuration");
        logger.error(ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();

        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Here is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>speed</groupId>
    <artifactId>speed</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Speed</name>
    <description>SPEED application for manufacturing</description>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>LOCAL</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <config.dir>configurations/dev</config.dir>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>TEST</id>
            <properties>
                <config.dir>configurations/test</config.dir>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>RELEASE</id>
            <properties>
                <config.dir>configurations/release</config.dir>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>



    <build>
        <finalName>speed2</finalName>

        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebRoot</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${config.dir}</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>

                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-el-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SP4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.enterprise.deploy</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jad-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-MR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.management.j2ee</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.resource</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-connector-api_1.6_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.auth.message</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaspi-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsp-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jstl-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxb-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.registry</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxr-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-saaj-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxws-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketbox</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketbox-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketbox-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-controller-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-dmr</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>async-http-servlet-3.0</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>aristo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>dot-luv</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jopendocument</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomahawk20</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.newpig</groupId>
            <artifactId>NPWebApp_SPEED</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.newpig.progress</groupId>
            <artifactId>Speed-User-Manager</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.newpig</groupId>
            <artifactId>fun_speed_theme</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
            <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
            <version>[0.4, 0.5)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.jbossas</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-varia</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>policy</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.jacc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jacc-api_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-xacml-project</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.GA</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jgroups</groupId>
            <artifactId>jgroups</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0.CR5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Do you think you could post the results of a `mvn dependency:tree` command from the command line, this might help determine if there is a conflicting Hibernate version issue.

Comment: Are you using any kind of Eclipse plugin when working with Maven? Looks like your dependencies for eclipse project and Maven POM are different. Plugin should keep those synchronized.

Comment: @dimoniy I am using m2e.

Comment: @SteveS Try to do Right-Click on the project -> Maven->Update.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It looks like when I converted the project, jboss tools included PicketBox. One of its dependencies is Hibernate 3.2.4. Once I removed the PicketBox dependencies all was good. I am not using it. I am sure there is a lot of stuff in there I really don't need to include. I will have to take some time to go through and clean up the POM. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found in the mvn dependenct:tree command that @drembert had me run. When I searched down through the tree for instances of Hibernate I found that one of my dependencies was pulling in an old version of Hibernate. As I didn't need that dependency (I think it was JBoss tools that added it for me) I removed the dependency and all started working fine.